# Eliminate scrollbar from main div in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

So I'm trying to design a register page with HTML , CSS and Bootstrap5  and i have 2 question :

1. In my code i have a navbar and a footer (i fix the  height of footer to 55px ; and I'm not sure if it's a good practice or no !!! because i want my footer to cover the social media icon and its height became equal to the height of my navbar )
   2)i want to remove the scrollbar from register form , so the full  "sign up" page will shown between my navbar and my footer and without that scrollbar
   [here is a pic for the page that i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfT9p.png)

   and here is my code

   ```
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-aaODHAgvwQW1bFOGXMeX+pC4PZIPsvn2h1sArYOhgXQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <style>

            .footer {
                margin-top: auto;
                position: fixed;
                left: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 55px;
                background-color: black;
                color: white;
                text-align: center;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <!-- Navbar -->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg  navbar-dark bg-dark">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
                            </li>
                         <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#" tabindex="-1" a>Login</a>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
      <main  style="background-color: #eee;">
      <div class="container h-100">
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-xl-11">
            <div class="card text-black" style="border-radius: 25px;">
              <div class="card-body p-md-5">
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                  <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-6 col-xl-5 order-2 order-lg-1">

                    <p class="text-center h1 fw-bold mb-5 mx-1 mx-md-4 mt-4">Sign up</p>

                    <form class="mx-1 mx-md-4">

                      <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4">
                        <i class="fas fa-user fa-lg me-3 fa-fw"></i>
                        <div class="form-outline flex-fill mb-0">
                          <input type="text" id="form3Example1c" class="form-control" />
                          <label class="form-label" for="form3Example1c">Your Name</label>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4">
                        <i class="fas fa-envelope fa-lg me-3 fa-fw"></i>
                        <div class="form-outline flex-fill mb-0">
                          <input type="email" id="form3Example3c" class="form-control" />
                          <label class="form-label" for="form3Example3c">Your Email</label>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4">
                        <i class="fas fa-lock fa-lg me-3 fa-fw"></i>
                        <div class="form-outline flex-fill mb-0">
                          <input type="password" id="form3Example4c" class="form-control" />
                          <label class="form-label" for="form3Example4c">Password</label>
                        </div>
                      </div>
              <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4">
                <i class="fas fa-key fa-lg me-3 fa-fw"></i>
                <div class="form-outline flex-fill mb-0">
                  <input type="password" id="form3Example4cd" class="form-control" />
                  <label class="form-label" for="form3Example4cd">Repeat your password</label>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-check d-flex justify-content-center mb-5">
                <input
                  class="form-check-input me-2"
                  type="checkbox"
                  value=""
                  id="form2Example3c"
                />
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="form2Example3">
                          I agree all statements in <a href="#!">Terms of service</a>
                        </label>
                      </div>

                      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mx-4 mb-3 mb-lg-4">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Register</button>
                      </div>

                    </form>

                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-6 col-xl-7 d-flex align-items-center order-1 order-lg-2">

                    <img src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/new-templates/bootstrap-registration/draw1.webp" class="img-fluid" alt="Sample image">

                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
        <footer class=" footer   ">
                <div class="container-fluid  position-b-0">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                            <h6>&copy; 2022 - . All right reserved.</h6>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                            <a style="color: #3b5998 ;" href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-facebook-f fa-lg"></i></a>
                            <a style="color: #55acee;" href="#"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-twitter fa-lg"></i></a>
                            <a style="color: #ac2bac;" href="#!"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-instagram fa-lg"></i></a>
                            <a style="color: #dd4b39;" href="#"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-google-plus fa-lg"></i></a>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </footer>
    </body>
    </html>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate the scrollbar you can add,

```
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

but it will make unable to reach the content at the bottom. So it is better to set the total content to 100vh or less.

Answer (score 0):

heres the sample for you. https://codepen.io/CrystalRcodes/pen/wvPQBdZ

If you want to hide the scrollbar you can use below code.

```css
body {
  overflow-y:scroll;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display:none;
}
```

but if you want to view the entire form on your computer you can use a specific height or use your specific viewport or like 100vh . But its gonna be tricky for other viewport.